# Random characters failing libc read

Tags: c, .net, ubuntu, io, libc

I'm writing a (dotnet) program that outputs random bytes to stdout.

These characters are then piped into another program that uses the libc `read` function.

```
{
  char v4[76]; // [rsp+0h] [rbp-50h] BYREF
  int buf; // [rsp+4Ch] [rbp-4h] BYREF

  read(0, &buf, 4uLL);
  if ( buf >= 0 )
  {
    read(0, v4, buf);
    return 0LL;
  }
  else
  {
    fwrite("Size must be greater than zero.\n", 1uLL, 0x20uLL, stderr);
    return 0xFFFFFFFFLL;
  }
}
```

Random characters such as below result in `buf` always less than zero.

`�0�S�52$N�CJ�p�7r�]�-?���1}n"��`

Any explanation for why is appreciated. The goal is to enter the `if` block.

Comment: I would suggest pasting the input as a hexdump (or base64) instead of raw.

Comment: Try setting your locale to C.UTF-8 or en_US.UTF-8. If locale doesn't change anything then what you're likely seeing is the effect of read using a signed char and promoting that to int without casting it to unsigned char first

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about this I think one of two things are happening:

## Possibility 1 -- You are simply not prepending your stream with a number of bytes.

The C code you linked looks at the first 4 bytes and expects them to be a ***signed int***, depending on the system that could mean multiple things but on most it would be a 32-bit signed integer storage class.

If instead it is pseudo-random bytes there is a 50:50 shot that your first bit will always be setting it negative.

## Possibility 2 -- Your byte order is being converted in dot net without you realizing it when you write to the stream.

Functions like `htonl` and `ntohl` exist to solve this problem. In C you can find those in <arpa/inet.h>.

Try setting your `int` number of of bytes to network byte order prior to piping if you are indeed writing them and then convert them back to host byte order when they land.